# Determining when a socket has been closed on Android

Tags: android, c++, linux, sockets, networking

On Windows and iOS, I'm currently doing the following:

```
//sock is defined as a valid socket.
fd_set socketsRead;
fd_set socketsWrite;
fd_set socketsExcept;
FD_ZERO(&socketsRead);
FD_ADD(sock, &socketsRead);
FD_ZERO(&socketsWrite);
FD_ADD(sock, &socketsWrite);
FD_ZERO(&socketsExcept);
FD_ADD(sock, &socketsExcept);
timeval timeOut;
timeOut.tv_sec = 0;
timeOut.tv_usec = 100;
bool read, write, except;
if (select(sock + 1, &socketsRead, &socketsWrite, &socketsExcept, &timeOut) == SOCKET_ERROR) {
    read = false;
    write = false;
    except = true;
} else {
    read = FD_ISSET(sock, &socketsRead);
    write = FD_ISSET(sock, &socketsWrite);
    except = FD_ISSET(sock, &socketsExcept);
}

if (read) {
    long availableData;
    ioctlsocket(sock, FIONREAD, &availableData);
    if (availableData == 0) {
        //Connection is closed.
    }
}
```

On Android, it doesn't seem to work.  It keeps thinking the connection is closed right when I make connection.  That is, read flag gets set, and `FIONREAD` returns `0` right when connection is made.

Comment: In java you have to use the `java.nio`, Selector & Channels. Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/nio/channels/SocketChannel.html)

Comment: Just because there is no data to read *now* doesn't mean the connection is closed.

Comment: @ja_mesa He doesn't have to use Selectors and Channels in Java. He can use Sockets.

Comment: @EJP The BSD documentation mentions that if you get a read bit, but no date, it means the connection has been closed. I mentioned in my self-answer that the bug was just the definition of `FIONREAD` was different on Android than it was on Windows and iOS.

Comment: You haven't *done* a read. You have obtained FIONREAD, which is the number of bytes that can be read *without blocking.*

Comment: @EJP Take note of the `select()` - if there's a read bit, it means there is at least one byte that can be read, or a connection is closed when there is indeed no data to be read.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Seems `FIONREAD` was incorrectly defined - it was using the Windows/iOS constant value instead of the Android one.

Comment: Irrelevant. FIONREAD cannot tell you whether a socket has been closed.

Comment: Reread the documentation. Number of bytes that can be read without blocking. The sender hasn't sent anything for a while. He might be about to so so. Nothing 'uneducated' about it. Don't be offensive.

Comment: If you read my original question, it mentions that I determine closed status when there is a read bit set, but FIONREAD returns 0.  It's documented that when the read bit is set and there's no data, it means the connection has been closed.  This successfully works on all platforms.